TypeError: 'NoneType' Object Cannot Be Unpacked When Starting Browser with nodriver on Python 3.12
I'm trying to debug an error occurring with nodriver when I attempt to start a browser session. The code used to work but now raises an error after updating to a new setup. Here is a simplified script to reproduce the issue:
import nodriver as uc
import time
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

async def test_nodriver():
    agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
    try:
        browser = await uc.start(headless=True, browser_args=[f"--user-agent={agent}"])
        logging.info("Browser started successfully")
        page = await browser.get("https://www.nowsecure.nl")

        time.sleep(1)

        await browser.start.save_screenshot("image.png")
        logging.info("Screenshot saved successfully")
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Failed to start browser: {e}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uc.loop().run_until_complete(test_nodriver())

Error Traceback
After running this script, I get the following error traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/project/src/test_nodriver.py", line 22, in <module>
    uc.loop().run_until_complete(test_nodriver())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/asyncio/base_events.py", line 687, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/me/project/src/test_nodriver.py", line 10, in test_nodriver
    browser = await uc.start(headless=True, browser_args=[f"--user-agent={agent}"])
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/me/project/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/nodriver/core/util.py", line 96, in start
    return await Browser.create(config)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/me/project/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/nodriver/core/browser.py", line 91, in create
    await instance.start()
  File "/home/me/project/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/nodriver/core/browser.py", line 394, in start
    await self.connection.send(cdp.target.set_discover_targets(discover=True))
  File "/home/me/project/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/nodriver/core/connection.py", line 420, in send
    await self._prepare_headless()
  File "/home/me/project/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/nodriver/core/connection.py", line 499, in _prepare_headless
    response, error = await self._send_oneshot(
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object

Environment Information

OS: Linux Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Python: 3.12.6
nodriver: 0.37
Chromium: 130.0.6723.69 (installed via Snap)

Description of the Issue
From the debug logs, it appears nodriver is failing to initialize the browser connection. I suspect it could be an issue with the version compatibility between nodriver and Chromium or with how nodriver is handling WebSocket communication in headless mode.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue with recent versions of Python, nodriver, or Chromium? Is there a workaround or a configuration tweak that can resolve the NoneType error during the browser startup process?
